# how to set single request timeout in ApacheBench?

Tags: timeout, apachebench

how to set single req timeout in ApacheBench?

I try to use "-s" to set it and expect add it to "failed request" if it timeout. but it seems not work property, there are some req spent more than 1 sec. as blow total max is "3698" and more than 1 sec.

---

[ApacheBench output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3U21.png)